# Sharepoint: Retrieve info on assigned user policy

Tags: security

A question from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567916/sharepoint-retrieve-info-on-assigned-user-policy)

Case:

- Create a User Policy in SharePoint 2010 Web Application Management: assign 'Full read' to user XXX for site YYY;
- Call SiteData.asmx/GetContent for site YYY and inspect 'permissions' node.

User XXX is not assigned any permissions for site YYY according to WS call result.

How should I retrieve permissions of XXX for YYY via web services?
In which table assigned User Policy is stored in SharePoint Content database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the usergroup.asmx web service and call "GetGroupCollectionFromUser"

If the returned xml has the correct group in it:

```
Group[Name='<groupName>']
```

Then they have permission.

If you need there are also functions in usergroup.asmx to get things like role info etc.

**[MSDN usergroup.asmx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772647%28v=office.12%29.aspx)**

Comment: If I do so (assign a policy to the user that has never logged into the site before; login with this user to the SP site), then GetGroupCollectionFromUser returns empty result for me:
`
<GetGroupCollectionFromUser xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
  <Groups /> 
  </GetGroupCollectionFromUser>`

Comment: So you're not defining groups for roles and assigning groups? You would have to get the roles back for the user then. Then you would have to do something a little more complex with GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser. Where there is a will there is a way.

Comment: Could you please clarify the purpose of this method (GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser)? it returns me something even if I call it with invalid credentials, so who is 'current user' then?

Comment: It should be returning you permissions of basically you have none if the credentials are invalid.